How to use hook to change \parskip in minipage?
I try to use a hook to change the \parskip in the minipage environment. But my code doesn't work.
Here is an MWE.
\documentclass{article}

\AddToHook{env/minipage/begin}{\setlength{\parskip}{2em}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
        paragraph 1.
    
        paragraph 2.
    
        paragraph 3.
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
        \setlength{\parskip}{2em}
    
        paragraph 1.
    
        paragraph 2.
    
        paragraph 3.
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}

The \parskip of the first minipage have not been modified.
I have already known that
\newcommand{\@minipagerestore}{\setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}}

can achieve the effect I want. I just want to know why my code doesn't serve its purpose.

minipage is a peculiar environment which has had a hook from day one. Lamport's idea was that a minipage should start from a “clean sheet status” and have some code in common with \parbox (memory was scarce, remember). So minipage does some clean up before actually starting to typeset text: first it does
\@parboxrestore

then it sets up footnotes and lists (which is specific to minipage), does
\@minipagerestore

and finally does \@setminipage that sets \@minipagetrue at the beginning of every paragraph. What is \@parboxrestore? It's defined in terms of \@arrayparboxrestore (which stores code used also in p columns of tabular and array) and is responsible, among other things, for resetting \parindent, \parfillskip, \baselineskip and \parskip.
Actually, the default meaning of \@minipagerestore is \relax, but it's available for further settings a user wants to do in all of their minipage environments.
Note that all of this is done after the environment has started, in particular after the env/minipage/begin hook has been executed.
I concur that in an ideal world the code in \AddToHook{env/minipage/begin} should be executed as part of \@minipagerestore, but unfortunately hooks came forty years after the implementation of minipage.
One might imagine to do
\AddToHook{cmd/@minipagerestore/end}{\setlength{\parskip}{2em}}

but, alas, this doesn't work, because \@minipagerestore is defined by
\let\@minipagerestore=\relax

So you can do
\ExpandArgs{cc}\NewCommandCopy{@minipagerestore}{@empty}
\AddToHook{cmd/@minipagerestore/end}{\setlength{\parskip}{2em}}

Full example
\documentclass{article}

\ExpandArgs{cc}\NewCommandCopy{@minipagerestore}{@empty}
\AddToHook{cmd/@minipagerestore/after}{\setlength{\parskip}{2em}}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter\show\@minipagerestore

\noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
        paragraph 1.
    
        paragraph 2.
    
        paragraph 3.
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
        \setlength{\parskip}{2em}
    
        paragraph 1.
    
        paragraph 2.
    
        paragraph 3.
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}



The issue with your code is that the env/minipage/begin hook is not appropriate for modifying the \parskip inside the minipage.. Instead, you should define the \@minipagerestore command.
In the code I have presented below:
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@minipagerestore}{\setlength{\parskip}{2em}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
        paragraph 1.
    
        paragraph 2.
    
        paragraph 3.
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
        \setlength{\parskip}{2em}
    
        paragraph 1.
    
        paragraph 2.
    
        paragraph 3.
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}

You get the desired output:


I knew that @minipagerestore can do it, but why env/minipage/begin hook can't?

@houzw  @minipagerestore  is itself a hook. The env/minipage/begin hook did not work as it would come first and then overridden by the default parameters.

That;s true. I just wanted to get a proper working solution rather than explaining the underlying mechanism. I think @egreg 's answer is correct.
